# Schema verification/validation before loading data into HDFS/Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop2, sqoop

I am a newbie to Hadoop Ecosystem and I need some suggestion from Bigdata experts on achieving schema verification/validation before loading the huge data into hdfs.

The scenario is:

> I have a huge dataset with given schema (having around 200
>   column-header in it). This dataset is going to be stored in Hive
>   tables/HDFS. Before loading the data into hive table/hdfs I want to
>   perform a schema level verification/validation on the data supplied to
>   avoid any unwanted errors/exception while loading the data into hdfs. 
>   Like in case somebody tries to pass a data file having fewer or more
>   number of columns in it then at the first level of verification this
>   load fail.

What could be the best possible approach for achieving the same?

Regards,
Bhupesh

Comment: Please add details of the type of data file you have. The frameworks you have in mind along with source and destination of the data. Because, if you have xml/json file, you can perform validation straight away. if its tab separated, you can this of verifying in map reduce-mapper by counting the string array of input line after splitting based on tab. So please add more details and what option have you looked

Comment: I have csv/tsv files with me, which I want to move (put or copyFromLocal) to my HDFS (Hadoop cluster) and some in hive tables (LOAD DATA INTO...). Now, at the time of this storage; I want to perform some kind of validation on the number of columns and their respective types (present in those files) before moving the data of those files into HDFS or hive tables (to avoid any processing time hiccup - like datatype mismatch etc). You mentioned that with xml/json files this can be performed straight away, could you please help me with some pointers in that direction as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have files, you can add them into HDFS,and run map reduce on top of that. Here you would be having a hold on each row, so you can verify number of columns, their types and any other validations.

When i referred to jason/xml, there is slight overhead to make map reduce identify the records in that format. However with respect to validation there is schema validation which you can enforce and also define only specific values for a field using schema. So once the schema is ready, your parsing(xml to java) and then store them at another final HDFS location for further use(like HBase). When you are sure that data is validated, you can create Hive tables on top of that.

Answer (score 0):

Use below utility to create temp tables every time based on the schema you receive in csv file format in staging directory and then apply some conditions to identify whether you have valid columns or not. Finally load into original table.

https://github.com/enahwe/Csv2Hive